# jQuery .height() doesn't return the right value

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, margin

I have a website that needs to be fullscreen at every screen. For this reason I use alot of jQuery to determin the height, max-height, margins, ...

I have a margin-top on the container id. When i call the height, which is the base of determing the margin-top, at the end of the script, it does not give me the right amount.

As long as the height of the container id is not right in var containerh, var containert will not be right either.

```js
var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    var containerw = width * 0.9;
    var containerl = containerw * 0.5;
    var containerh = $("#container").height();
    var containert = containerh * 0.5;
    $("#container").css("margin-left", "-" + containerl + "px");
    $("#container").css("margin-top", "-" + containert + "px");
    alert($("#container").height());
```

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    h1 {
      font-family: 'Hobo';
      color: #0070c0;
      font-weight: lighter;
    }

    font {
      color: #ed27b9;
    }

    #container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 46%;
      left: 50%;
    }

    video {
      border: 2px solid #134963;
    }
```

```html
<center>
  <div id="container">
    <center>
      <h1>Leur <font>&#171; experience &#187;</font> en quelques mots...</h1>
    </center>
    <center id="boven">
      <video class="video2" frameborder="0" poster="../beelden/image39.png" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen controls>
        <source src="../video/film1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="../video/film1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            <source src="../video/film1.webm" type="video/webm">
              Your browser does not support the video tag
      </video>
      <video class="video2" frameborder="0" poster="../beelden/image40.png" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen controls>
        <source src="../video/film1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="../video/film1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            <source src="../video/film1.webm" type="video/webm">
              Your browser does not support the video tag
      </video>
    </center>
```

Can anyone help me with the margin-top and height of the container? It returns 552px at my screen, but the height of the container id is 546px

what i have [example](http://aikodedoncker.donboscohalle.net/FIV/pages/parcours.html)

Comment: Can you clarify "fullscreen at every screen"? Normally you just apply height 100% to both `html` and `body` in the CSS, then apply fixed heights to required elements within `body`.

Comment: it has to be in every screen size, without stretching horizontally or vertically, but by scaling down equaly. the margins should also scale with the screen size.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand your requirements from the text descriptions provided. Can you draw a simple diagram of the desired layout (e.g. in Paint) and add that to the question? This is after all really a design problem, more than a code problem.

Comment: i shall put an example in the description of what i have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`$("#element").outerHeight();`

or

```
$("#element").innerHeight();
```

according to your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

use outerHeight to calculate height of element including border and padding.

```
$("#element").outerHeight(); // height + padding + border
```

or If you want to add margin of element also

```
$("#element").outerHeight(true); // height + padding + border + margin
```